# gzdecode files in python

Tags: python, gzip

i have an error to use this and I do not understand

```
import glob
import zlib
import sys

for filename in sys.argv:
    with open(filename, 'r') as compressed:
        with open(filename + "-decompressed', 'w') as expanded:
        data = zlib.decompress(compressed.read())
        expanded.write(data)
```

error

```
    with open(filename + "-decompressed', 'w') as expanded:
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You incidentally used one double quote and one single quote to close the string. Should be

```
 with open(filename + '-decompressed', 'w') as expanded:
```